# Error deploying Django Application

Tags: python, django, apache

I am trying to deploy my first Django application on a server with Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. 
I installed apache and something else:

```
apt-get install apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils libexpat1 ssl-cert
```

Then I installed wsgi module:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

I edited the ports.conf to listen on port 8080, as I already have another server on port 80 where I host html+js+css resources (they are correctly available). 
After this preparation step, I moved my Django application on the new Apache server, specifically into the html directory. Then edited the apache2.conf file by adding the following:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/MyProjectName/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/MyProjectName

<Directory /var/www/html/MyProjectName>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

The rest of configuration directives is the default I get after installing Apache with the given commands.

Then, I noticed that in the `mods-available` folder, I had the wsgi module, but not in the `mods-enabled` folder, so I created a symbolink link into this last folder.

When I start Apache, if I open localhost:8080, I get an internal server error. Accessing the error.log file, I see the following:

```
[Mon Mar 09 16:38:20.730865 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 24379:tid 140525609281408] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 09 16:38:20.731257 2015] [core:notice] [pid 24379:tid 140525609281408] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Mar 09 16:38:28.673948 2015] [:error] [pid 24383:tid 140525514131200] [client 127.0.0.1:41038] mod_wsgi (pid=24383): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/MyProjectName/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Mar 09 16:38:28.674120 2015] [:error] [pid 24383:tid 140525514131200] [client 127.0.0.1:41038] mod_wsgi (pid=24383): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/MyProjectName/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Mar 09 16:38:28.674240 2015] [:error] [pid 24383:tid 140525514131200] [client 127.0.0.1:41038] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Mar 09 16:38:28.674299 2015] [:error] [pid 24383:tid 140525514131200] [client 127.0.0.1:41038]   File "/var/www/html/MyProjectName/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
[Mon Mar 09 16:38:28.674438 2015] [:error] [pid 24383:tid 140525514131200] [client 127.0.0.1:41038]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Mon Mar 09 16:38:28.674480 2015] [:error] [pid 24383:tid 140525514131200] [client 127.0.0.1:41038] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

**Where do I start understanding the problem?** 
**My understanding is that somehow the Apache WSGI module is not working.**

For completeness, the wsgi.py file I am pointing at looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MyProjectName.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

sys.path.append('/var/www/')
sys.path.append('/var/www/html/')
sys.path.append('/var/www/html/MyProjectName')
```

The settings file is as follow:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
SECRET_KEY = '<some_key_here>'

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'anothercustomapp',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'MyProjectName.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'MyProjectName.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'MyDatabaseName',
        'USER' : '<username>',   
        'PASSWORD' : '<password>', 
    }
}

SERIALIZATION_MODULES = {
    'json': 'wadofstuff.django.serializers.custom_json'
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'it-IT'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

At the path /var/www/html/ I have the following structure:

- A folder called MyProjectName, containing the wsgi.py file, as well as a settings.py file, urls.py and an empty **init**.py
- A folder called anothercustomapp, containing urls, models, views and admin python files, other than an empty **init**.py
- A folder called wadostuff, used to serialize to json and containing the same files as anothercustomapp (in terms of names)

================EDIT================

After installing Django and python-mysqldb with the following commands:

```
apt-get install python-setuptools
easy_install django
apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

I end up having the following error.log:

```
[Mon Mar 09 16:52:13.610937 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 24789:tid 139911380785024] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 09 16:52:13.611288 2015] [core:notice] [pid 24789:tid 139911380785024] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Mar 09 16:52:18.056083 2015] [:error] [pid 24792:tid 139911285634816] [client 127.0.0.1:41213] mod_wsgi (pid=24792): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/MyProjectName/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Mar 09 16:52:18.056256 2015] [:error] [pid 24792:tid 139911285634816] [client 127.0.0.1:41213] mod_wsgi (pid=24792): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/MyProjectName/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Mar 09 16:52:18.056302 2015] [:error] [pid 24792:tid 139911285634816] [client 127.0.0.1:41213] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Mar 09 16:52:18.056346 2015] [:error] [pid 24792:tid 139911285634816] [client 127.0.0.1:41213]   File "/var/www/html/MyProjectName/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
[Mon Mar 09 16:52:18.056485 2015] [:error] [pid 24792:tid 139911285634816] [client 127.0.0.1:41213]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Mon Mar 09 16:52:18.056514 2015] [:error] [pid 24792:tid 139911285634816] [client 127.0.0.1:41213]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.6-py2.7.egg/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Mon Mar 09 16:52:18.072789 2015] [:error] [pid 24792:tid 139911285634816] [client 127.0.0.1:41213]     django.setup()
[Mon Mar 09 16:52:18.072882 2015] [:error] [pid 24792:tid 139911285634816] [client 127.0.0.1:41213]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.6-py2.7.egg/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
[Mon Mar 09 16:52:18.088060 2015] [:error] [pid 24792:tid 139911285634816] [client 127.0.0.1:41213]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Mon Mar 09 16:52:18.088166 2015] [:error] [pid 24792:tid 139911285634816] [client 127.0.0.1:41213]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.6-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
[Mon Mar 09 16:52:18.097590 2015] [:error] [pid 24792:tid 139911285634816] [client 127.0.0.1:41213]     self._setup(name)
[Mon Mar 09 16:52:18.097632 2015] [:error] [pid 24792:tid 139911285634816] [client 127.0.0.1:41213]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.6-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
[Mon Mar 09 16:52:18.097692 2015] [:error] [pid 24792:tid 139911285634816] [client 127.0.0.1:41213]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Mon Mar 09 16:52:18.097725 2015] [:error] [pid 24792:tid 139911285634816] [client 127.0.0.1:41213]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.6-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 98, in __init__
[Mon Mar 09 16:52:18.097778 2015] [:error] [pid 24792:tid 139911285634816] [client 127.0.0.1:41213]     % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
[Mon Mar 09 16:52:18.097833 2015] [:error] [pid 24792:tid 139911285634816] [client 127.0.0.1:41213] ImportError: Could not import settings 'MyProjectName.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named MyProjectName.settings
```

Comment: No, the problem is it's not finding Django. How/where did you install it? Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: Thanks, good point, I installed Django and edited the OP to include the new error I get. No I am not using virtualenv.

Comment: You should move your sys.path.append lines to before the call to get_wsgi_application.

Comment: OK, now I get 400 Bad Request no matter what url I type. No useful info is in the error.log. Where can I look for additional info on the cause of this error?

Comment: Is the DEBUG setting set to True?

Comment: 400 Bad Request is usually because `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in settings.py does not match the Apache virtualhost

Comment: It was not. The issue was in the url mappings. Fixed also this other issue. I think last issue is about serving Django admin static files: I don't see css files.

Comment: to get admin css, run `./manage.py collectstatic`